# Image Conversions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I converted an RGB image (which is in double format) to a gray scale image of the same format using `rgb2gray` in Matlab. Now I want to convert the same image from gray to RGB. I used `gray2rgb` in Matlab but it's giving an error. So how can we convert a grayscale image to an RGB image using Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say it's not possible.
By converting the image to grayscale you've reduced the amount of information (3 dimensions at each pixel down to 1) and this can't be recovered.

The `rgb2gray` function is one included in Matlab and works fine.
The `gray2rgb` function is not a standard Matlab function. If you are referring to [this function on Matlab central](http://www.mathworks.us/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28111-gray2rgb), it's documentation states it doesn't do anything useful but just creates a 3d matrix from the 1d matrix; the image will still be grayscale.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. Not perfectly at least.

As Sean says, this is because you have dropped some information when converting to grayscale. In other words, converting back from grayscale to RGB is an *under-determined inverse problem*, so there is no *easy* solution.

Now this doesn't mean you can't try. If you have some prior on the image, you can use it in addition to the information you have left to compute an *estimate* of the original RGB image.

For example if you know (or suppose) that the original image was already grayscale (in an RGB container) then you can reverse the process exactly. This is what the `gray2rgb` function Sean mentions is doing.

Most of these are open problems, so it's probably beyond what you want.